# Lateral Force on a Fin

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

I am wondering what the lateral force is on the *fin* of, say, an arrow, (or other *befinned missile*) as a function of the angle through which it is turned ... or more particularly what it's   *dependence on the angle* is. By a naïve argument it could be held to be a ̸θ² dependence, as both the area that the fin *presents* to the airflow *and* the angle through which the flow is *turned* are proportional to ̸θ. But this is not *necessarily* so, I might imagine, as the the interaction of the flow with the fin is not simply that of its *impacting* a *target* of a certain size, but rather of the entire flow for some distance around the fin being altogether *reshapen*. I have not been able to find a straightforward answer to this through a web 'conjuration' of academic papers - but I suspect that whatever the solution is, the *Schwarz-Kristoffel transformation* should play a major rôle in it.

And in addition, the solution to the equation of motion, given *some* intial rate-of-turning as boundary-condition, becomes a *really quite appalling* one with an elliptic integral in it (although I'm sure it can be simplified: the ***Wolfram™*** online integrator is notorious for returning solutions in an extremely *raw* form!) ... but nature doesn't care about *that*, of course!

Intuitively there is a certain *repugnance* in the idea of the lateral (& therefore *restoring* force) having θ² dependence, as such dependence might be held to admit of rather large *swings* of the missile about orthobaticity, by reason of its thereby having a significant *latitude* in which to swing without the restoring force even *beginning* significantly to increase.

But maybe they *do*! I can't honestly say I have often closely observed an arrow in flight.

Answer (score 1):

Aerodynamically, a fin works the same way as a wing. For small angles of attack $\theta$ to the airflow, the "lift force" is proportional to $\theta$. For large angles of attack where the airflow may stall, etc, there is no simple "formula."

The theory of the flow around airfoils is well established, Textbooks would be a better place to find it than research papers, since there isn't likely to be any research effort being done on a well-known standard theory. Beware of web sites, though, since there is a lot of total nonsense about this on the web.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(force) is as good a place to start as any - note section 2.4 on "Alternative explanations, misconceptions, and controversies" if you look elsewhere on the web.

Comment: Right! ... thanks for that. I'm sure you appreciate that the simple logic that both _area presented to the flow_ and _lateral displacement of flow_ are _both_ poportional to the angle, and that lateral force might be supposed to  be proportional to the product of these, is one that is sufficiently compelling to occasion a refutation. I do realise that at least in _subsonic_ flow the fluid doesn't just propel the thing propelled by _slamming into it_ - that the fluid sets up a _complete system_ of flow about the _thing propelled_. But even so, I did need to hear from soneone explicitly

Comment: & specifically that lateral force _is_ proportional to ̸θ rather than ̸θ². I didn't really think of looking it up under _ærofoils_, as the kind of fin I am talking about is just a simple flat plate, such as on a dart or arrow, & I think of ærofoils as having a specific cross-sectional _shape_; so I didn't search under that heading. Nevertheless - the theory of flat plate still does come under it, then. As for my saying _academic papers_: I really just meant PDF files on the subject in the public domain that can be downloaded, which includes _many_ a textbook. And cranksites - seen 'em alright!

Comment: Flat plates (and pretty much any sensible looking shape) will generate lift quite efficiently. The main reason why aerofoils have fancy shapes is to minimize drag, not to maximize lift.

Comment: Right! ... Hmmm! ... I thought it was to make the speed of the flow greater over the upper surface greater than over the lower surface.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey: This answer is right. What makes airfoils work is that they have sharp trailing edges and they impose a circulation (change the direction of the airflow), resulting in a momentum flux (lift coefficient) proportional to $\theta$ up to the stall angle. The stall angle depends on many things.

Comment: _Circulation_  - yes - that you can also get around a rotating sphere or cylinder through the _no-slip_ conditiion.